# Recursive Array Flattener

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm doing a simple recursion exercise - an array flattener using recursion instead of a nested for loop. Can anyone let me know what I am missing?
Thanks a lot!

```js
function arrayFlattener(arr) {
  
//make an empty array for the result
let arrayCopy = []

//for loop through the arr
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  
  //stor arr[i] in var. called element
  let element = arr[i]
  
  //if element is array => call recursive arrayFlattener(element)
    if (Array.isArray(element)) {
      
       //push subElement to arrayCopy
       arrayCopy.push(arrayFlattener(element))
    }
  //else element is not array and can be pushed element to arrayCopy
  arrayCopy.push(element)
  
}
  return arrayCopy
}
```

Comment: What seems to go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`arrayFlattener` returns an array, and therefore your `arrayCopy` variable will remain a multi-dimensional array. To fix this, use the javascript spread operator(`...`):

```js
if (Array.isArray(element)) {
      
  //push subElement to arrayCopy
  arrayCopy.push(...arrayFlattener(element))
}
else {
   arrayCopy.push(element)
}
```

Comment: also the `arrayCopy.push(element)` should be in an `else {}` block

Comment: @NickParsons yes, I'll add that to my answer